# how to create a multilanguage application with raw folder with mp3 file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp3, multilingual

i create w multichoice quiz application with sound. i save a mp3 file in raw folder.I want to make my application multilanguage. Also i create a class contain data for change a view and mp3 file.

How  could I do  ?
Thanks

Comment: What does the mp3 have to do with multi-language?

Comment: I haven't used it with `raw` but as it's under `res` it should work the same. So follow this documentation and create a `raw` folder for each targeted languages https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages
Then the app will automatically pick the correct file based on the app current language.

Comment: @javdromero the mp3 is a voice recorder. I want to record in others language

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question, the raw files are already there and you want themto be separated by language OR you want to record some sound, create a .mp3 and then stored separated by language in folders?